# Windows bluescreen

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluescreenview

My laptop just finished updating over night and I turned it on and waited a while so that everything would load up (which took a bit longer than usually) and then I opened Blender 3d (modeling program) and this bluescreen just appeared, it's not the first time that a bluescreen has appeared after opening Blender 3d, but when it (the bluescreen) has appeared (about 3 times) windows takes care of the problem.

The bluescreen says:

**Stop code: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL**

**What failed: nvlddmkm.sys**

It has stayed at 0% complete for about 40 minutes now (since 5:00 pm).

Comment: IRQ Not Less or Equal almost always crops up in the case of damaged RAM.  Either your system RAM or the graphics card RAM.  You should test those to rule out a hardware problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to get back through your steps. Usually the BSOD (blue screen of death) appears after a driver install or like in your case, after an update... or even worse... after a bad not finished update.

Try to boot in safe mode and recover the last good state known! maybe you can get the state of your system like before the update (and the problem) happens... it only modify system, not user data files.

A link about how to boot in safe mode on W10. [Link](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)

Another link about how to rollback to last good known configuration, at the bottom is the W10 part. [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/220986/how-to-use-all-of-windows-10%E2%80%99s-backup-and-recovery-tools/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hold the power button for a longer time to force a shutdown. Now start the device again.

The `nvlddmkm.sys`means your BSOD is caused by the nVIDIA GPU driver. [So go to nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) and get the latest driver for your GPU.